# Move Swiper Pagination to Top of Swiper Container

Tags: css, pagination, swiper.js, html-framework-7

I would like to move the pagination bullets to the top of the viewing area, from the bottom.

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

Currently, the pagination bullets show below all wrapper or JavaScript appended slide content. I would like it to appear above that.

More info: https://framework7.io/docs/swiper.html#default-swiper-with-pagination

Answer (score 12):

only add padding bottom on swipper-wrapper and remove bottom on pagination

html

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.swiper-wrapper{
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets, .swiper-pagination-custom, .swiper-pagination-fraction{
    bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

solved

Answer (score 4):

This worked better for me, as my slides are of uneven size:

```
.swiper-pagination {
    top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out - fairly simple, but I don't know my CSS yet.

```
.swiper-pagination {
    bottom: 95%;
}
```

Modify the bottom or top properties.

Comment: This works for me, I am not sure why messing with the top: 2px will cause the entire slider to fail.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. open swiper>modules>pagination>pagination.less
2. at the top line where the *:root {...}* sits, uncomment the line **--swiper-pagination-bottom** and **--swiper-pagination-top**
3. edit the value of those variables to the following

```
:root {
        --swiper-pagination-bottom: auto;
        --swiper-pagination-top: 8px;
}
```

If you use CDN to import the module,

1. add the code above as option parameter as below

```
const params = {
injectStyles: [`
    :root {
        --swiper-pagination-bottom: auto;
        --swiper-pagination-top: 8px;
    }
...
}
```

2. initialize the swiper - complete main javascript file code may look something like this

```
const swiperEl = document.querySelector('swiper-container')

const params = {
    injectStyles: [`
    :root {
        --swiper-pagination-bottom: auto;
        --swiper-pagination-top: 8px;
    }

    ...
      `],

    pagination: {
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
            return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + "</span>";
        },
    },
}

Object.assign(swiperEl, params)

swiperEl.initialize();

....
```

Hope it works on your side!

Answer (score 1):

```
swiper-container {
  --swiper-pagination-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

If you're using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper with angular and if one of your div.swiper-slide has a different height, it's better to use this property :

css

```css
.swiper-pagination {
    bottom: calc(100% - 2rem);
}
```

For some reasons, when I tried to use the top css property on .swiper-pagination class, it disabled click event inside the div.swiper-slide with ngx-swiper-wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will be helpful to anyone, but I was able to do this by just styling the Swiper container w/ `flex / flex-direction: column;`, then I just re ordered the pagination stuff by setting it's `order` to `order: -1;`

Answer (score 0):

For Swiper Element in an project using SCSS this can be done by overriding the CSS variable. For example, in my Angular Ionic project

```css
:host {
    --swiper-pagination-top: 2px;
}
```